# Sonarqube add multiple test sources

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have my sonarqube configured the following way on a multi-module gradle project.

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property("sonar.projectKey", "key")
        property("sonar.organization", "org")
        property("sonar.host.url", "https://sonarcloud.io")
    }
}
```

This configuration is on the root `build.gradle.kts`.

I now have a integration test folder that I added using the `jvm-test-suite` plugin and I want these sources to show up as well on Sonarqube.

I've added this config:

```
            property("sonar.tests", "src/test, src/integrationTest")
```

But made no difference. They don't show up.

Any ideas? Thanks